# how to use ubuntu OEM installation?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, oem

I searched on how to prepare ubuntu as a template or alternatives for windows sysprep for ubuntu.

one of the suggestions I found is to use virt-sysprep which I tried and found quit difficult to understand and use.

the second option I found was ubuntu oem install- which seemed (at the time) much easier to use. I couldn't find a guide for using oem via cli, but after reviewing https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview, it seemed simple enough. so I went ahead and installed the latest ubuntu version (18.04.3) on a new VM (vmware) and customized it the way I want it to be.

now I would like to "prepare the machine for shipping". I found I should use "oem-config-prepare" but it doesn't exist! if I want to use it I need to install it with apt-get (it's ~850 dependencies and total size of ~400MB).

what am I missing? am I doing something wrong? what is the point in oem installation mode if oem-config can be (or in my case required) installed with apt?

P.S
when installing ubuntu I chose the oem option from the menu..

Comment: "OEM" installation is for pre-installing Ubuntu Desktop on computers. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds like it is not appropriate.

Comment: What host customization do you want removed, and how was that difficult with virt-sysprep ? The simple case is  `virt-sysprep -a disk.img`  but its operations can be customized, so be specific.

Comment: when I prepare a windows vm template (in vmware) I usually install windows regularly, customize it (install packages, change certain settings and etc). clone the machine, run sysprep on the clone (from the vm guest os) and convert to a template. I want to do something similar with ubuntu. from what I understand virt-sysprep is used from the host (not an option on vmware). I want to generalize the machine from the guest OS itself, causing on next boot to be prompted for a new hostname, user, password and etc..